# There is a way to use lsp4e for calling language server methods directly?

Tags: eclipse, language-server-protocol

I'm new to the lsp4e & lsp technologies and as far as I have seen the framework provides almost everything for working with eclipse. However there is a way to use this features at will? i.e I would like to use the LS to get all the functions on a file, I think this will be done with `textDocument/documentSymbol` but how can I get this using the lsp4e framework?

NOTE:
I checked for SymbolKind and seems it was not the one I was looking for however that input helped me finding a sample of DocumentSymbol

```
DocumentSymbolParams params = new DocumentSymbolParams(
new TextDocumentIdentifier(documentUri.toString()));
CompletableFuture<List<Either<SymbolInformation, DocumentSymbol>>> symbols = 
languageServer.getTextDocumentService().documentSymbol(params);
```

Comment: I guess this is done by lsp4j which implements LSP independent of Eclipse so it can be used also in a plain Java application. Eclipse lsp4e is based on lsp4j and integrates it into the Eclipse IDE (extends the _Generic Text Editor_, adds the _Language Servers_ preference pages, etc.). Have a look where [`SymbolKind`](https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4j/blob/master/org.eclipse.lsp4j/src/main/java/org/eclipse/lsp4j/SymbolKind.java) is used since this is what you want to get, right?

Comment: I checked for SymbolKind and seems it was not the one I was looking for however that input helped me finding a sample of DocumentSymbol  


```DocumentSymbolParams params = new DocumentSymbolParams(new TextDocumentIdentifier(documentUri.toString()));
 CompletableFuture<List<Either<SymbolInformation, DocumentSymbol>>>  symbols = languageServer.getTextDocumentService().documentSymbol(params);```

Comment: Great. You might give a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked for SymbolKind and seems it was not the one I was looking for. However that input helped me finding a sample of DocumentSymbol

```
DocumentSymbolParams params = new DocumentSymbolParams(
new TextDocumentIdentifier(documentUri.toString()));
CompletableFuture<List<Either<SymbolInformation, DocumentSymbol>>> symbols = 
languageServer.getTextDocumentService().documentSymbol(params);
```